# Update index not taking effect immediatly Apache Centos

Tags: php, apache, centos, webserver

With Apache on Centos, when I do modification to index.php, it doesn't take effect on my_website.com or [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
However, I can see the update on those links:

- my_website.com/index.php
- *<IPAddressOfMyServer>*

All above links points on same IP address on DNS configuration

I have done a lot of research about it, httpd.conf is very well, `DirectoryIndex index.php`
I tried `Redirect / https://my website.com/index.php`, nothing!
NB: this website was hosted by hosting company, and I have recovered this virtual machine on my server. But when it was hosted by this company, when I do update on index.php, it takes effect immediatly, but now while hosting on my own server, it takes effect in approximately about 24 hours.

Comment: Hey, it sounds like a cache issue. It would be easier to help you if you could show your HTTP Headers when you request your website (you can use a command `curl -I http://your_website.com` for this purpose, remember to remove sensitive information before posting it here).

Comment: Hello,
Result of commande `curl -I http://your_website.com` :
`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2022 12:50:17 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https:/my_webSite/index.php
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: Oh no, you still have the `Redirect` on, please remove it, and then test.

Comment: By changing `Redirect https://my_webSite.com/index.php` to `Redirect https://my_webSite.com`, I got same result of command `curl` in exception of line `Location: https:/my_webSite.com` instead of `Location: https:/my_webSite.com/index.php`

Comment: Okay, please let me know the results of `curl -I https://your_website.com/index.php`

Comment: Well, it seems to be a problem due to security equipements cache, if someome has the same problem than me ... Think about cache !!!
@Exampleperson thanks a lot for your help